# Java 11 Jasper report compilation error: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException

Tags: java, jasper-reports, java-11

Getting following error when jasper report compile in Java 11:

> ERROR [net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler] (default
> task-94) Compilation error:
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
> [Server:app-node-00]  at
> deployment.app.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.(ClassFileReader.java:329)
> [Server:app-node-00]  at
> deployment.app.ear//net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler$1.findType(JRJdtCompiler.java:251)
> [Server:app-node-00]  at
> deployment.app.ear//net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler$1.findType(JRJdtCompiler.java:187)
> [Server:app-node-00]  at
> deployment.app.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:97)

We are using jasperreports-javaflow-6.5.1.jar.

Comment: What jdt/ecj version do you have?

Comment: There is no jar like this in the classpath. Checked the ClassFormatException class and it's in core-3.2.3.v_686_R32x.jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

org.tolven.library.jboss-rules.core-3.2.3.v_686_R32x.jar, assuming that it's the same file as [the one here](https://github.com/dubrsl/tolven/tree/master/org.tolven.library.jboss-rules/jars), seems to be a very old ([released in 2007](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt/core/3.2.3.v_686_R32x)) JDT compiler implementation that's not able to read classes compiled for Java 11.

For Java 11 you'll need a more recent JDT version, for instance [4.4.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler/ecj/4.4.2).  But then there's a risk that the code that depends on the 3.2.3 JDT implementation no longer works with the more recent JDT version, in which case I don't know what you can do.

You might also need to upgrade the JasperReports version, according to [the change log](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/changes.txt#L205) support for Java 11 has been introduced in 6.8.0.

Comment: Eclipse ECJ 4.6.1 is compatible with jasperreports-javaflow-6.18.1.jar? Also currently using iText-2.1.7.jar.

Comment: JasperReports 6.18.1 specifies [ECJ 3.21.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt/ecj) (which is newer than org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:4.6.1) as dependency.  You can try with newer versions (I see the latest at this moment is 3.27.0), it might work.  iText 2.1.7 is fine.